# Não consigo publicar apk

Tags: android

Eu gerei uma keystore com 10 anos, ja testei com varios anos diferentes, e nada sempre aparece isso:

Você enviou um APK assinado com um certificado que expira em breve. Assine seu APK com um certificado com data de expiração mais distante.

Answer (score 3):

De acordo com a [documentação](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) um aplicativo para ser publicado no Google Play precisa que a assinatura dele tenha uma validade que vá até depois de 22 de outubro de 2033, sendo que o tempo recomendado por eles para a geração da chave é de 25 anos.